# the Console.WriteLine method in java. to build a string

Tags: java

In C# there is a method to write a string to the Console.

it is `Console.WriteLine("Hello {0} My name is {1}", "World", "John");`

this would return

```
Hello World My name is John
```

How can i recreate such a method structure in java. So that i can pass in unlimited amount of the parameters in the end of my method and get it placed in the right indexes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

// EDIT

Maybe i have not explained well enough. I do not need the method to make a console output. I just want to know how can i recreate a structure in which i can pass as many parameters as i want and get it placed in the right place. For example

movie.setPlot("This movie is {0} and gets a rating of {1}", "FUN", "6 Thumbs up");

which would set the the plot varialbe for a movie to

```
This movie is FUN and gets a rating of 6 Thumbs up
```

// EDIT 2

End Result:

```
private static final String PREFIX = "AwesomeApp";

    public static void e(String TAG, String msg){
        android.util.Log.e(PREFIX + "  >> " +TAG,  msg);
    }

    public static void e(String TAG, String msg, Object...args){
        e(TAG, String.format(msg, args));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `var-args` to handle an indeterminate number of parameters:

```
void setPlot(String text, String... args) {
   System.out.printf(text, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class introduced in Java 5, like this:

```
Formatter f = new Formatter();
f.format("Hello %s my name is %s", "World", "John");
System.out.println(f.toString());
```

**Edit:** (in response to the edit of the question) You can use a formatter in the implementation of your own custom method, like this:

```
private String plot;

void setPlot(String formatStr, Object... data) {
    Formatter f = new Formatter();
    format(formatStr, data);
    plot = f.toString();
}
```

You can now call your `setPlot` function like this:

```
movie.setPlot("This movie is %s and gets a rating of %s", "FUN", "6 Thumbs up");
```